# CS50 pset5 Speller Error in unload function

Tags: c, cs50

:( program is free of memory errors

valgrind tests failed; rerun with --log for more information.

This is the only error I get. I don't know what exactly is the issue or how to solve it.

```
// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int buckets = 5490;

//Number of words in dictionary
int wordCount = 0;

// Hash table
node *table[buckets];

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    char dictionaryWord[LENGTH + 1];

    while (fscanf(file, "%s", dictionaryWord) != EOF)
    {
        node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory available to load %s.\n", dictionary);
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(newNode->word, dictionaryWord);

        int index = hash(dictionaryWord);

        if (table[index] == NULL)
        {
            table[index] = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->next = table[index];
            table[index] = newNode;
        }
        wordCount++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    //iterate through every 'bucket'
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets; i++)
    {
    node *root = table[i]; // initially points to 1st node

    while(root != NULL)
        {
           node *tmp = root; // tmp points to root
            root = root -> next; // root points to next node
            free(tmp); // tmp frees the prior node
        }
   }

    return true;
}
```

When I run valgrind

It says

Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value? Take a closer look at line 129 of dictionary.c.

Line 129 refers to

```
while(root != NULL)
```

in the unload function

Comment: How is `table` defined and initialized? Do all elements hold a defined value?

Comment: please show [mcve].

Comment: Did you take the advice `rerun with --log for more information`?

Comment: After the `while` loop `table[i]` still points to the already `free`d memory. Do you use it somewhere? Why don't you do a `table[i] = NULL;` after the `while` just to be sure?

Comment: I would assume `table[i]` is not initialized for some `i` and Valgrind complains about `root` now containing such an indetermined value

Comment: I just uploaded some more of my code here.

Comment: `root->next` contains indetermined values for the first entry in each list. In other words, your lists are not terminated properly. This is because `newnode` does not hold any defined content after you got the pointer from `malloc`.

Comment: @Gerhardh so what exactly am I supposed to do?

Comment: What does the C50 material tell about creating lists? Terminating the list would be a good idea. If you insert a new "last node" the `->next` pointer should hold `NULL`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you so much. it solved the problem

Comment: [CS50 Pset5 Load Function - Questions/Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+cs50+pset5)